Where am I wrong in proving that force perpendicular to motion increases speed and kinetic energy?
Lets think of a helicopter flying at some height $h$. It throws a food packet to a person on the ground from air. Let's neglect the air drag.
The food packet is thrown only with some velocity $v_x$ in the $x$ direction. The only force acting on the food packet after it has been thrown is gravity, perpendicular to its motion, $-mg$. So we know that the food packet attains some velocity $v_y$ $(-gt)$ and acceleration ($-g$) in the $y$ direction.
So the velocities are $v_y$ and $v_x$. At time $t$, the total velocity magnitude will be $\sqrt{{v_y}^2 + {v_x}^2}$. The magnitude of velocity is called speed. So the speed will bee clearly increasing as $v_y$ will be increasing with time.
Concluding our journey, we had a food packet with some velocity in $x$ direction at some height and just after the very very small moment it has been released, it had a force $-mg$ perpendicular to its motion. But the packet gains some velocity in y direction as it falls and so the final velocity will be much greater than $v_x$ (it will be $\sqrt{{v_x}^2+{v_y}^2)}$. As the speed of the object increases the kinetic energy also increases thus disproving that "if the resultant force acting on a particle is perpendicular to its velocity, the kinetic energy does not change".

Two things: The expected way this site works is questions are posed and answered. Blogs don't fit the format. Second, It isn't the component of force perpendicular to the velocity that changes the speed and kinetic energy. It is the component parallel. The perpendicular component changes the direction of velocity but not its magnitude. In this case, the hozontal component of velocity doesn't change. The vertical component grows.

@mmesser314 Two things: It isn't a blog, its a question(I believe it was the the title which was causing the confusion. I have edited it now)  to why is my assertion being true. Second: gravitational force is downwards, how can it have a component parallel to the motion. If you'r saying that gravitational force is parallel to the y direction then yes and it is growing vy. But that disproves what my textbook says "if the resultant force acting on a particle is perpendicular to its velocity, the kinetic energy does not change", there was net one force present perp. and it changed kinetic energy,

If the force stayed perpendicular to the velocity, the speed would stay the same. This is like a planet in circular orbit around the sun. For the helicopter, the speed does not change at the starting instant, when force and velocity are perpendicular. It just changes direction. After that instant, they are no longer perpendicular.

@mmesser314, your answer seems correct. Thanks.

First, I am using $z$ for the vertical direction.
The eq. of motion are:
$$ \frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2} = \frac 1 m \vec F = -g\hat z $$
or:
$$ \ddot x = 0 $$
$$ \ddot y = 0 $$
$$ \ddot z = -g $$
which is solved with:
$$ \vec v(t) = \vec v_0 -gt\hat z $$
The scalar product of force and velocity is:
$$ \vec F \cdot \vec v = \vec F \cdot (\vec v_0 -gt\hat z) $$
$$ \vec F \cdot \vec v = (-mg\hat z)\cdot (-gt\hat z)= mg^2t \ne 0 $$
Note that this is the power input from gravity, so:
$$ P(t)= mg^2t = \frac d {dt} \frac 1 2 mv^2 $$
So is your complaint that $P(0) = 0 $?
At $t=0$, that addition of a small vertical component of the velocity does not increase its magnitude to 1st order, since:
$$ |\vec v|=
\sqrt{v_x^2 + (gt)^2}$$
$$ |\vec v|=
v_x\sqrt{1 + (\frac{gt}{v_x})^2}\approx v_x\Big(1 + \frac 1 2 \big(\frac{gt}{v_x}\big)^2\Big)\rightarrow v_x$$
So all that happens in that instance is that the velocity is rotated (to first order), and once that happens, power can be input.
Edit: I want to add some commentary to the terse answer. It's a good question. If the initial power input is zero, how does it ever become non-zero? E.g., with circular motion, the force is never aligned with the velocity, and the energy never changes.
So in this case, it really is explained by Taylor Expansion--and when I learned physics, one of the most difficult jumps to make was accepting expansions.
In school, you are raised on exact analytic solutions as you work your way up....then you are introduced to
$$(1+\epsilon)^n = 1 + n\epsilon + \cdots $$
an it's a tough pill to swallow. It's the first time you realize you can't have all the answers. This is only compounded in  quantum mechanics class, where the atom is one big approximation. Many question on this site are the result of forgetting that fact, or misunderstanding what it means to the physical interpretation of the math.
Understanding both the limits of, and how to exploit, approximations is a critical physics skill.
I think this problem provides a great example of why we need them, and the subtleties of how to use them.
We all know:
$$ \cos\theta = 1 -\frac 1 2 \theta^2 + \cdots $$
and
$$ \sin\theta = \theta + \cdots $$
The first thing is that as $\theta\rightarrow 0$, $\theta^2$ is truly irrelevant. So as gravity acts on the horizontally moving mass, the power input is zero at $t=0$ for a total duration of $\Delta t = 0$, but in this time, the vector is rotated an infinitesimal amount, but the vector points in the direction of the force, relative to it's lengthening, by $1/\theta\rightarrow \infty$...which allows power to input in spite of initial zero dot product.
The power input is linear in $\theta$, and that's enough to start inputing power with at first, not inputing power for an infinitesimal time.

Seems correct to me. Thanks
